# Usefulness of @ARGV in Perl

Tags: perl

What is the difference between using just normal arrays and the special array (command line argument)?

Normal array: `@num(1,2,3,4)`, and you can use `$num[0]`, etc

Special array: you have to use `@ARGV`, and becomes `$ARGV[0]`, etc.
Is it similar to `while (<>)`?

What is the whole purpose of using `@ARGV` instead of a normal array?

Comment: You have asked five questions here. All five have a negative voting. The first three have already been closed. Does that tell you anything? For how long do you intend to continue this way?

Answer (score 2):

The `@ARGV` array isn't special, it's a normal array that happens to be predefined. It's just a global variable that contains the command line arguments when the program starts. You use it to access the command line arguments.

There is also an `ARGV` filehandle and an `$ARGV` scalar. The `$ARGV` scalar is normal, but it is set automatically to the current file name when reading from `ARGV`. The `ARGV` scalar is special: `<ARGV>`, or its synonym `<>`, automatically treats each element of `@ARGV` as a file name and opens the files and reads from each in sequence.